# Filter response and store something in memcached using nginx+Lua

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I have a backend which generates three JWT tokens - reference token, access token and refresh token. Reference token stores a reference to the access token, which is used to access API and refresh token is used to reissue access token when it is timed out. The problem is I do not want to pass access token to the client, but want to use nginx to store it in memcached. So, my whole task is to filter the response from the backend, which currently looks as simple as:

```
{"reference_token":"...","access_token":"...","refresh_token":"..."}
```

Nginx should filter this response, get access token from this response and store it in memcached. Finally, it should return to the client a new response:

```
{"reference_token":"...","refresh_token":"..."}
```

As you can see, there should be no access_token any more. Access token is something which I try to secure and not to show it and even pass it to the client. What I do not know, is what is the best approach to implement this, what Lua block should I use for this task. I know about [body_filter_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#body_filter_by_lua) , but documentation shortly says that:

> Note that the following API functions are currently disabled within this context due to the limitations in NGINX output filter's current implementation

So, it seems like body filtering is rather limited and I'm not even sure if it is possible to call memcached API inside this block. So, how can I implement my task in real world? At least, what Lua (openresty) tricks should I use to approach this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may issue a subrequest (e.g., ngx.location.capture) to your backend within you content handler for example.
Next you may filter a body as you want and use then lua-resty-memcached which use cosocket API.

The drawback of this approach is that you would have full buffered proxy.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander! Can you please a bit elaborate on why full buffered proxy is a drawback? I'm new to nginx and do not know these nuances.

Comment: Imagine upstream server responds with huge body. Usually it would be sent in some chunk. Nginx processes every chunk and by default sends it back to client without waiting for full response  body. It saves some resources and is more performant. With full buffered approach you will need to save headers/body somewhere. If you save it in memory you may have swapping under high load. If you save it in a file - you would have IO overhead.